# FB.logout: what should it do in term of later calls to FB.getLoginStatus?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

> The method FB.logout() logs the user out of your site

what does this mean in terms of later calls to FB.* functions?

Specifically, I'm observing that even though the response to FB.logout has a status of "unknown", after the logout has completed, calling FB.getLoginStatus returns a status of "connected", when passing true as a second parameter or after a page refresh.

This is unexpected to me... perhaps I'm misunderstanding what "logs the user out of your site" means: what does it mean in terms of the FB.* functions? I'm looking to, as best as possible, reverse the process of `FB.login`. How can this be done?

---

Update: I was testing at http://localhost:8080. When on http://fbtest.charemza.name/ I realise logout works as I expect, but logout on localhost:8080 logout does *not* seem to work, i.e. exhibits the problem above. To be clear, no errors appear in the console at any point. The code of the page is below.

To change the question slightly, why does it do this on localhost:8080, and is there a way to develop logout locally where the behaviour is the same as on the public web?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Facebook Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '1524395480985654',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : false,
        status     : false,
        version    : 'v2.10'
      });

      FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      document.getElementById("loginButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          console.log('FB.login', response);
        });

      });

      document.getElementById("logoutButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          console.log('FB.logout', response);
        });
      });

      document.getElementById("getLoginStatusButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          console.log('FB.getLoginStatus', response);
        }, true);
      });
    });
  </script>


  <button id="loginButton">FB.login()</button>
  <button id="logoutButton">FB.logout()</button>
  <button id="getLoginStatusButton">FB.checkLoginStatus()</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested and it works great for me. Run `FB.logout(function(resp){console.log(resp);})` in console and see if you get any errors. Can you see in chrome Developer Tools->Network if there are any error? Are you running any IFrame on your site?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, the initial response to Logout does work as I expect. However, a subsequent call to getLoginStatus suggests has connected, and so nothing seems to have changed. No errors or iframe.

Comment: I checked `getLoginStatus` also multiple times after logout, i tried refresh page and every possible combination. I always get status `unknown`. Can you check if it makes the call in networks tools when you execute `getLoginStatus`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Ah... if you pass true as the second parameter to getLoginStatus, to force a refresh from the server, what does it do?

Comment: Still works, see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxjjR.png

Comment: I did try to reproduce this issue but it looks fine. Do you have any js code to show us how to reproduce this scenario?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Does it do the same thing if the user is already logged into Facebook before the initial call to FB.login ?

Comment: Yes, In my case it works both ways. Whether I am already logged into facebook or I use incognito window without existing FB login

Comment: @TarunLalwani I was testing on localhost:8080. Testing on a globally accessible page it seems to work fine... ideally I would still want to develop this locally.

Comment: @TomMelo I have added the JS, as well as more specific information regarding localhost.

Comment: @MichalCharemza, You need to make sure you have separate APP created for the same and url set as `http://localhost:8080`, like i did in https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnXZJ.png. My testing was all through `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Ah sorry... I did change the settings in the app when testing for each domain. Right now for example, 'App domains` is set as `localhost`  and `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` contains `localhost:8080`, and I see the problem when the page is served at `localhost:8080`

Comment: Try creating a new app and no need to set app domain and Valid OAuth redirect URIs, just set the website url and see if it works on local

Comment: @TarunLalwani That's it! (With empty OAuth redirect URIs), with `localhost` in "App domains" I see the problem. However, with "App domains" empty, it works as expected. Feel free to add an answer. (Ideally with an explanation?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156654/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-michal-charemza).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work for you on localhost is that you have set the App domains to `localhost`, app domains should only be set when you are using a actual domain.

So I went through a debugging session on the Javascript loaded by FB JSSDK and found below line

```
document.cookie = n + "=" + o + (o && p === 0 ? "" : "; expires=" + r) + "; path=/" + (q ? "; domain=" + j : "")
```

When you have no `App domains` set then `q=null` and `j=.localhost`. So no domain is set on the cookie and hence it all works great.

When you have a `App domains` set as `localhost`, `q=true` and `j=.localhost`. So when the code tries to set domain it uses something like below

> "fbsr_370363483399260=q8i_dn0F22UweXRMNff0tf5WpfYOelZ0vsjtIKrDhzw.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI....A4NTgwNzg1MzEwOTk5In0; expires=Fri, 13 Oct 2017 14:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.localhost"

This doesn't work on localhost and doesn't allow setting the cookie at all. document.cookie will not set any cookie not related to current page. But if I override `j=localhost` in console the cookies work. That is the reason you shouldn't set `App domain` to `localhost` when testing locally

[image: FB Cookies on local]

Comment: When it tries to set a cookie using `domain=.localhost`... is that actually a bug on Facebook's part?

Comment: It's not a bug, they don't expect you to work on localhost and at the same time use `App domains`

Comment: Ah... I'm now reading from https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html that cookie domains must have at least two or three periods/dots. Is this why it fails for `.localhost`?

Comment: I can workaround the localhost issue another way. I can add `127.0.0.1 local.charemza.name` to `/etc/hosts`, and then I can set the App domain to be `local.charemza.name` (say, to make it similar to the real case), and then the logout works fine as well when assessing my local version at `http://local.charemza.name:8080`

Answer (score 0):

> The method FB.logout() logs the user out of your site and, in some
>   cases, Facebook.

This means:

1. **Steps**: User not logged in Facebook -> Logins into your app

   **On FB.Logout**: User will log out from your app and Facebook
2. **Steps**: User not logged in Facebook -> Logins into **some other app**.  -> Logins into your app

   **On FB.Logout**: User will log out from both the apps and Facebook
3. **Steps**: User *already logged in Facebook* -> Logins into your app

   **On FB.Logout**: User will log out from your app but not facebook.

(Note: If User is not logged in Facebook, he/she will have to first log into Facebook and then your app)

So in all cases the user has to be logged in with facebook so when you use FB.getLoginStatus following things will happen:

1. User Logged into Facebook and your app is authenticated.

   FB.getLoginStatus returns *connected*
2. User logged into Facebook but has not authenticated your application

   FB.getLoginStatus returns *not_authorized*
3. Now if the user logs out of Facebook or logs out of your app (which may results in log out from Facebook). *(This seems to be your case)* **Because in this case, the app doesn't even make an attempt to connect to facebook, that's why unknown.**

   FB.getLoginStatus returns *unknown*

EDIT:

Now in third case it will always return unknown because it doesn't even try to connect to Facebook. So if you pass force true, it will attempt to make a ajax call to Facebook and will return you the status (should either be connected or not_authorized).

```
function getLoginStatus(cb, force) {
  if (!Runtime.getClientID()) {
    Log.warn('FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().');
    return;
  }
  if (cb) {
    if (!force && loadState == 'loaded') {
      cb({
        status: Runtime.getLoginStatus(),
        authResponse: getAuthResponse()
      });
      return;
    } else {
      Auth.subscribe('FB.loginStatus', cb);
    }
  }
  if (!force && loadState == 'loading') {
    return;
  }
  loadState = 'loading';
  var lsCb = function lsCb(response) {
    loadState = 'loaded';
    Auth.inform('FB.loginStatus', response);
    Auth.clearSubscribers('FB.loginStatus');
  };
  fetchLoginStatus(lsCb);
}
```

Above function taken from Facebook SDK will fetchLoginStatus if force is true.

Comment: It seems like the problem was that it didn't return unknown, and instead it returns connected.

Comment: It's one of the case, which is now explained in the Edit.